# MakeSignature.signDetached throws IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, pdf-generation, itext, digital-signature, hsm

while using `MakeSignature.signDetached` to apply digital signature to PDF using LUNA HSM 1700.

Please guide me to resolve this issue.

Thanks In Advance.

Method as below:

```
public static void Digital_signed(String SRC,String DEST) 
throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException, DocumentException , Exception{
    try {
        char[] pkcs11PIN = "devicepassword".toCharArray();
        Provider p = null;
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(configFileName);
        p = new SunPKCS11(fis);
        String provide_name =p.getName();
        Security.addProvider(p);
        KeyStore ks =  KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS11","SunPKCS11-Luna");
        ks.load(null, pkcs11PIN);
        String alias = (String)ks.aliases().nextElement();
        PrivateKey pk = (PrivateKey) ks.getKey(alias, pkcs11PIN);
        Certificate[] chain = ks.getCertificateChain(alias);
        TSAClient tsaClient = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < chain.length; i++) {
            X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate)chain[i];
            String tsaUrl = CertificateUtil.getTSAURL(cert);
            if (tsaUrl != null) {
                tsaClient = new TSAClientBouncyCastle(tsaUrl);
                break;
            }
        }

        List <CrlClient> crlList = new ArrayList<CrlClient>();

        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(SRC);
        FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(DEST);
        PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.createSignature(reader, os, '\0');
        PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.getSignatureAppearance();
        appearance.setVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(700, 820, 760, 780), 1, "sig");
        ExternalSignature pks = new PrivateKeySignature(pk,  DigestAlgorithms.SHA256, provide_name);
        ExternalDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();

        MakeSignature.signDetached(appearance, digest, pks, chain, crlList, null, tsaClient, 0, CryptoStandard.CMS);
    }  
    catch(Exception e)
    {}
    finally{ }
}
```

ERROR AS BELOW:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The name 'iText? 5.5.0 ?2000-2013 iText Group NV (AGPL-version) (AGPL-version) (AGPL-version) (AGPL-version) (AGPL-version) (AGPL-version) (AGPL-version)' is too long (143 characters).

Comment: This is inherent to using the AGPL version of iText. Licensed versions do not show this behavior.

Comment: Thanks Bruno,Is is possible to resolve the issue without licenced version?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you wouldn't use a licensed version? The cost of such a license isn't as high as the cost of an HSM.

Comment: Thanks once again for your instant reply, you are absolutely right,I have already sent inquiry to iText sales team.The reason behind my question was that I wanted to run the code without error till the time we buy the license.

Comment: In the meantime, we've tracked the problem in the AGPL version. It will be fixed in iText 5.5.3.

Comment: We have released iText 5.5.3 which fixes this problem in the AGPL version.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Could you extract an answer out of this so this won't sit here forever? Thanks for the fix!

Answer (score 0):

There was a problem with the `Version` class in the version of iText you were using. We have now `synchronized` the operation and starting with iText 5.5.3, the problem should have disappeared. If not: please let me know and we'll take another look at the problem.